# Data is showing MvcMiniProfiler results. Is that expected?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer, security

Not sure if this is actually desired, but [data](http://data.stackexchange.com) is currently showing me (a SE non-dev) [mvc-mini-profiler](/questions/tagged/mvc-mini-profiler) results, including all queries that are being run against the DB (not talking about data-explorer queries of course, talking about site rendering queries).

[image]

New feature of [data](http://data.stackexchange.com) or a deployment whoops?

**Edit:**

I didn't realize that data was [an open-sourced project](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/).  With that in mind, this probably isn't a security problem after all, and is in fact more likely [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yep, this is indeed [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). You can read more about the profiler on [waffle's blog](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/06/09/+Profiling+your+website+like+a+true+Ninja), including the part where he mentions that you can check it out live on the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).