# What is the number shown on the top left part of the page in the Data Explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Data is showing MvcMiniProfiler results. Is that expected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102999/data-is-showing-mvcminiprofiler-results-is-that-expected)

I thought the number was showing how much time the executed query took, but I see that number also in the login page.

[image: screenshot]

In a page showing a query, after I execute that query, I see more than one number.

[image: screenshot]

What does effectively that number mean? Why do I see more than one number (it could also be 5 numbers)?

Comment: Probably to show server load from executing other queries.

Comment: See [Data is showing MvcMiniProfiler results. Is that expected?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102999). I can answer the bit about the multiple numbers if you want, but it's not particularly interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the output of the [MVC mini profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) - a tool written by the Stack Overflow team and that is used to measure the performance of a page.