# Miniprofiler is visible on data explorer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer

I am able to see the mini profiler on the data explorer.

[image]

Isn't this supposed to be only visible to employees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not on the data explorer - this is also a bit of a showcase of the profiler.

There is nothing wrong.

[This is by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102999/data-is-showing-mvcminiprofiler-results-is-that-expected).

Comment: So that's intended?

Comment: @KyleTrauberman - yep.

Comment: Ahh. Interesting.  I never noticed it until now.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman - indeed a **mini** profiler then ;)

Comment: indeed, indeed. :P